# Fire a code when permalinks updated

Tags: permalinks, filters, rewrite-rules

I would like to execute some php code when permalinks updated, I think some plugins I'm using them updates permalinks programmatically sometime and this breaks my some slug rewrite settings, at this point I need to run code when permalinks updated. Is there any filter or event listener to make me able to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know you can use the post_updated or the save_post hooks

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_updated/ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/

Hope that this help. If you need any other info please let me know.

Update:
Sorry for my misunderstanding. You can use the the_permalink filter. Below you have the docs

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but it's not about a specific post, I mean when updating site permalinks `wp-admin/options-permalink.php` I need to catch that moment

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you Fintina, how i didn't think exact named `the_permalink` filter name, i don't know  Thank for your help.